# How can I use std::codecvt_utf8_utf16 to convert to and from utf8 without any string class?

Tags: c++, c++11, unicode, utf-8, utf-16

How can I use `std::codecvt_utf8_utf16` to convert from uft8 to utf16 and back **without** using any string class such as `std::string` or `std::wstring` but only plain arrays and literal strings? How can I know the right size of the buffer I need to store the conversion?

For example to meet this interface:

```
std::unique_ptr<char16_t[]> ToUTF16(const char* utf8String);
std::unique_ptr<char[]> ToUTF8(const char16_t* utf16String);
```

Comment: The size information gets lost with pointers, so you can't.

Comment: Why don't you want to use string classes? Doing so becomes a no-brainer using `std::wstring_convert` to facilitate the conversion, and you can pass literals and arrays to it as input. Using `std::string` and `std::u16string` is easier than using `std::unique_ptr` arrays. At the very least, if you must return a `std::unique_ptr` array, you could use `std::wstring_convert` for the conversion and then copy the resulting string characters to an output array. The array size will be the string size.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm using custom made containers (strings, vectors etc. that aren't stl) due to strong requirements on memory management such as stateful allocators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by using the [`codecvt_utf8_utf16` members directly](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8_utf16). Your first step is to find the length of the input with `strlen` (assuming it's NUL terminated). `codecvt` members work off of ranges, so you need to know how big your input is.

However, a problem arises: the length of the output buffer. While `codecvt` does have a `length` member, it will only compute the length for conversions using `in`. That is, conversions from UTF-8 to UTF-16. There is no length method for doing the other conversion.

As such, the only way to handle this is to convert some of the data to a buffer of known size. If the conversion isn't fully finished, then convert some more of the data. After all that's done, put all of the pieces into a buffer now that you know how many characters are going to be there.

While your question says that you don't want to use strings, I'm going to use `vector<T>` for that because if I didn't, I'd just be *rewriting `vector`*. And there's no reason to do that.

```
std::unique_ptr<char16_t[]> ToUTF16(const char* utf8String)
{
    auto end_ptr = utf8String + std::char_traits<char>::length(utf8String);
    std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t> converter;
    std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>::state_type state;

    std::array<char16_t, buffer_size> buffer;
    std::vector<char16_t> storage;

    auto curr_in_ptr = utf8String;
    auto out_loc = buffer.begin();

    do
    {
        std::codecvt_base::result rslt = converter.in(state,
            curr_in_ptr, end_ptr, curr_in_ptr,
            buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), out_loc);

        storage.insert(storage.end(), buffer.begin(), out_loc);
    }
    while(curr_in_ptr != end_ptr);

    //+1 for NUL terminator.
    std::unique_ptr<char16_t[]> ret(new char16_t[storage.size() + 1]);
    std::copy(storage.begin(), storage.end(), ret.get());
    ret.get()[storage.size()] = char16_t();
    return ret;
}
```

The other code works in the same way, except that `in` becomes `out`, and the `char16_t`'s and `char`'s are swapped.

Comment: _wcstrlen doesn't work because char16_t is not wchar_t_ ... use `std::char_traits<char16_t>::length( str )`

Comment: @zett42: Excellent. Thank you.

Comment: I only suggest to add a check for `std::codecvt_base::result` in case of `error` in the while loop and remove the unused `old` variable :) .

Comment: While you do not know the exact length of the UTF-8 conversion, you do know an upper bound on it: each two-byte UTF-16 character will translate to at most three bytes of UTF-8, and each four-byte surrogate pair will translate into at most five bytes of UTF-8.  Therefore, you can reserve a vector of three bytes per UTF-16 character and resize to fit afterward, improving the worst-case performance dramatically.

Comment: @Davislor: "*each four-byte surrogate pair will translate into at most five bytes of UTF-8*" At most four bytes. While UTF-8 technically could have a 5 byte encoding, Unicode's codepoint range doesn't go high enough to use a 5 byte encoding. 10FFFF, the largest Unicode character, can fit into 4 bytes of a UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: @NicolBolas Similarly, two digits are enough to store any calendar year in the twentieth century, 32 bits can store any timestamp up to 2038 and no file is more than 2GiB large?  Regardless, the takeaway here is that either 5/4 or 4/4 is less than 3/2, so three bytes per UTF-16 character is the safe upper bound.

Comment: @Davislor: No, 3-bytes per UTF-16 code *unit* is a safe upper bound. UTF-16 "characters" can require one or two 16-bit code units. Also, Unicode *cannot* use more than 10FFFF codepoints, because UTF-16 surrogate pairs are incapable of encoding more codepoints than this. So your notion of what might happen in the future is simply impossible.

Comment: I’ll try to remember your preferred terminology.  Good point on the upper limit of surrogate pairs.  In the future, some character set might, I suppose, require surrogate triples, or maybe by then UTF-16 will be so obsolete that no one updates the format.  But we both agree that the safe upper bound is the number of 16-bit array elements times three bytes.

Comment: According to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt/in), one must initialize the `std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>::state_type` local variable by assigning it the value of `std::mbstate_t()`. Not sure why this isn't happening automatically, but in my testing, that variable otherwise remains uninitialized in both MS Windows (with Visual Studio 2019) and Linux (with gcc). The call to `in()` under MS Windows failed until I initialized the `state` variable.